# simple insert to database with jquery ajax json and serialize()?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem, I want to use jquery ajax to simply input database.

this my code **tes.php**

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     //alert('$'); 

      $('.SAVE').click(function(){
        //alert('&');

        var name = $('.NAME').val();
        var alamat = $('.ALAMAT').val();

        //alert(name);
        //alert(alamat);

           $.ajax({

              type:"POST",
              dataType:"json",
              url:"tes2.php",
              data:$('#COBA').serialize(),
              success: function(response) {

                   alert(response);


               },


           });      

      });


  });


</script>

<form id='COBA'>
  <input type='text' name='NAME' class='NAME' value='septiyo'><br>
  <input type='text' name='ALAMAT' class='ALAMAT' value='semambung'><br>
  <input type='submit' value='SAVE' name='SAVE' class='SAVE'>
</form>
```

and **tes2.php**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['NAME'];
$alamat = $_POST['ALAMAT'];

print_r($_POST);



?>
```

But it dont work, I Hope can Get the data On tes2.php so I can Process it 
with query.

can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, but you can't see it because when you click on the button, it will refresh the page, you need to prevent default behaviour of the submit button :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.SAVE').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // ---- this
    var name = $('.NAME').val();
    var alamat = $('.ALAMAT').val();

       $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          dataType:"json", // remove this if you did't want any response
          url:"tes2.php",
          data:$('#COBA').serialize(),
          success: function(response) {
               alert(response);
           },
       });      
  });
 });
```

Or give `type='button'` on save button. Remove `dataType:"json"` if you doesn't want any response

Comment: Hi sir, I have try all your advice but still not work and nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `method="post"` to your form. Add change input from `"submit"` to `"button"`.

[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3Cscript%20src='jquery.js'%3E%3C/script%3E%5Cn%3Cscript%3E%5Cn%20$(document).ready(function()%7B%5Cn%20//alert('$');%5Cn%5Cn%20$('.SAVE').click(function()%7B%5Cn%20//alert('%2526');%5Cn%5Cn%20var%20name%20=%20$('.NAME').val();%5Cn%20var%20alamat%20=%20$('.ALAMAT').val();%5Cn%5Cn%20//alert(name);%5Cn%20//alert(alamat);%5Cn%5Cn%20$.ajax(%7B%5Cn%5Cn%20type:%22POST%22,%5Cn%20dataType:%22json%22,%5Cn%20url:%22http://phpfiddle.org/%22,%5Cn%20data:$('%2523COBA').serialize(),%5Cn%20success:%20function(response)%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%20alert(response);%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%20%7D,%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%20%7D);%5Cn%5Cn%20%7D);%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%20%7D);%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%3C/script%3E%5Cn%5Cn%3Cform%20id='COBA'%20method=%22post%22%3E%5Cn%20%3Cinput%20type='text'%20name='NAME'%20class='NAME'%20value='septiyo'%3E%3Cbr%3E%5Cn%20%3Cinput%20type='text'%20name='ALAMAT'%20class='ALAMAT'%20value='semambung'%3E%3Cbr%3E%5Cn%20%3Cinput%20type='submit'%20value='SAVE'%20name='SAVE'%20class='SAVE'%3E%5Cn%3C/form%3E%5Cn%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn$name%20=%20$_POST['NAME'];%5Cn$alamat%20=%20$_POST['ALAMAT'];%5Cn%5Cnprint_r($_POST);%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn%5Cn)

Comment: stil not work too, is I must use json.stringify or something? for know my data has send to tes2.php

Comment: Did you see my demo? Check you console.

Comment: I have see your demo, Ok it work, but How can I get it on my php variable? because I can echo ing that variable.

Comment: I copied your code as-is added method="post" on the form and changed the url to post to the same page. So my guess would be that there something wrong with your page url. Check if your network tab in the browser when you click the save button

Comment: Ok it work, it because json. if i use html it work like charm. :D thanks for helping

Comment: Might be your php version.Which version are you using?

Comment: I user [PHP: 5.5.15] on xampp,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106686/discussion-between-reagan-gallant-and-uchsun).

Answer (score 0):

Write data:{NAME:name,ALAMAT:alamat}
This will pass your data to tes2.php.

Comment: But I want use serialize because my form full of input text